# What's wrong with this rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have a helper class in rails that has a method like this:

```
def doSomething(name, *args)
 result = ""
 args.each do |arg|
  if (name == 'something')
   result += arg
  end
 end 
 result
end
```

My rspec method to test is like this:

```
it "Should return a hex array for normal input" do
  expect(helper.doSomething("somename", 1, 2,3, 4,5)).to eq("")
end
```

When I run the rspec I run into the following error:

ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT::::

Sorry folks this is not the complete code. I tried to create something similar but in correcting my previous code I discovered the error in some other part.

Comment: couldn't your helper be something simpler like `args.map(&:to_s).join if name=='something'`?

Comment: We need more info to help you. Can you include the full stacktrace (not just the error message: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)` but the set of lines showing which class and what line eg `myproject/app/models/my_model.rb:42` -> these lines (and there's usually about 30) are the stacktrace lines and they let us tell *which* line of code caused the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great if you could include the stack trace from the error as well. Your test looks correct except for the fact that you are trying to add fixnums to a string at `result += arg`, which will result in an implicit conversion error.

I'd say fix that first, and if the problem still exists, please post additional information.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're missing array syntax in your rspec method.

Right now your doSomething method has 6 arguments in rspec when it should have 2 arguments(which it does when you establish it in your helper). Try to refactor this part of your rspec test ("somename", 1, 2,3, 4,5) *The numbers should be in array syntax.

Comment: This is not a problem thanks to the ruby splat operator in the method declaration (*args). See: http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_methods.html